# the behaviour of Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, tabs, start-activity

I used the following code to bring up SignInActivity and, at the same time, clear all others:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SignInActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

My app has multiple tabs, and SignInActivity is one of the tab activities:

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup(getLocalActivityManager());
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator(createTabView(this, "Home", R.drawable.home)).setContent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class)));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("lists").setIndicator(createTabView(this, "My List", R.drawable.shopping_list)).setContent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShoppingListActivity.class)));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("stores").setIndicator(createTabView(this, "Stores", R.drawable.store_finder)).setContent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StoreActivity.class)));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("my_card").setIndicator(createTabView(this, "My card", R.drawable.more_card)).setContent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class)));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("more").setIndicator(createTabView(this, "More", R.drawable.more)).setContent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MoreActivity.class)));
```

At the time of execution, there was a TransactionActivity running, and the code (the first chunk of code showed above) was called from the transaction activity. I expected that the transaction activity to be cleared, and the original SignInActivity being brought to top. But what I actually observed was that, a new SignInActivity was started instead of just bring to top the original one; and when I clicked back button, the transaction activity showed up, which indicates that it was not cleared; when I click back again, the original SignInActivity showed.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the entire history of started activities and then start an activity from fresh, i use the following code:

```
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
```

I personally use it when the user logs out of my application, then clear the history of all activities that require a login and show the login activity again.